# How to show info message without using ONCLICK / button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error-messages

Please let me know if there is a way to show a message right after opening a Lightning Page for three/few seconds and continue. I need this function to be happened without pressing any button. Once the page is opened, it should show the custom message and disappear after three seconds and continue with normal PAGE. Please suggest me if there is a way to do this in LIGHTNING.. 
I have a piece of code, please let me know if I can include that in **init** controller along with previous/original page code??

```
errMessage: function (cmp, event, helper){
    //helper.error(cmp, event);
    var invId = event.getParam("invId");
    var action = component.get("c.errMessage");
    var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:ShowMessage");
    action.setParams({
        "invId": invId
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var err = a.getReturnValue().toString();
        var returnStringArr = err.split(':'); 
        var msgType = returnStringArr[0];
        var msg = returnStringArr[1];
        setTimeout(function() {
                myEvent.setParams({"msg": msg, "msgType":msgType});
                myEvent.fire();
                }, 3000);
        )};
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Thanks in advance. Ashok

Comment: you can create a lightning component do the stuff you wanted to appear in `Init` function and place the component in lightning page

Comment: @vignesh       Thank you for the quick response. Please let me know if we can include above mentioned code in along with actual/existing controller or not.

Comment: You have already  another component in the page right ?  You mentioning "actual/existing controller" I cant get you clearly

Comment: Yes. I already have some code in the same _init_ controller of Lightning page. it is already calling a method _var action = component.get("c.checkInvoiceStatus");_ Now, I want to call another method on same class which is returning ERROR and I want to use above code to display that message.

Comment: Yes you can .What is `event.getParam("invId")`  Is there any event or method which calls the errMessage method .Now you calling in init it will return undefined, may be you can take care of that. And use `$A.getCallback()` to  `window.setTimeout()` in an event handler to execute some logic after a time delay.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm

Comment: Have you though of using lightning toasts? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation

Comment: _<aura:handler event="c:InvExist" action="{!c.errMessage}"/>_ InvExist is an event. I did initialized above code in COMPONENT and errMessage is not mentioned anywhere yet. I want to add complete function part of errMessage code into _init_ block of CONTROLLER. Please suggest if I can do that.

Comment: @Ranga         Can we use **Show Toast** without using Onclick or button function? If so, please let me know. I will give it a try. I think we should include that code in init part of controller of lightning page as VIGNESH said.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [force:showToast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation)
This basically shows a message which disappears after a few second.

Use **duration** parameter to specify the time interval.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead advise using the Toast from the [lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation) component.

When your component initializes, you can fire the event that will display the Toast, and specify the modality to `sticky` which will display it for 3 seconds:

using the init handler ->

```
({    
    handleShowToast : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('notifLib').showToast({
            "title": "Notif library Title!",
            "message": "Your Message",
            "mode" : "sticky"

      });
    }
})
```

in your component markup, you will have to use a `<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>` component.